# TypeError: "callback" argument must be a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, twitter, callback

So I'm following a guide to upload images to twitter w node using twit.

This is my code

```
    function upload_random_image(){
  console.log('Opening an image...');
  var image_path = path.join(__dirname, '/random_cam/' + random_cam()),
      b64content = fs.readFileSync(image_path, { encoding: 'base64' });

  console.log('Uploading an image...');

  T.post('media/upload', { media_data: b64content }, function (err, data, response) {
    if (!err){
      console.log('ERROR');
      console.log(err);
    }
    else{
      console.log('Uploaded an image!');

      T.post('statuses/update', {
        media_ids: new Array(data.media_id_string)
      },
        function(err, data, response) {
          if (!err){
            console.log('Error!');
            console.log(err);
          }
          else{
            console.log('Posted an image!');
          }
        }
      );
    }
  });
}
```

Maybe I'm missing something with the callback function, I know if had to be a function but I can't see why my func is not working.

Error:

```
throw new TypeError('"callback" argument must be a function');
```

Full code:

```
var Twit = require('twit')

var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    Twit = require('twit'),
    config = require(path.join(__dirname, 'config.js'));


var T = new Twit(config);

function random_cam(){
  var random_pic = [
    '1.jpg',
    '2.jpg',
    '3.jpg'
  ];
  return random_pic[Math.floor(Math.random() * random_pic.length)];
}


function upload_random_image(){
  console.log('Opening an image...');
  var image_path = path.join(__dirname, '/random_cam/' + random_cam()),
      b64content = fs.readFileSync(image_path, { encoding: 'base64' });

  console.log('Uploading an image...');

  T.post('media/upload', { media_data: b64content }, function (err, data, response) {
    if (err){
      console.log('ERROR');
      console.log(err);
    }
    else{
      console.log('Uploaded an image!');

      T.post('statuses/update', {
        media_ids: new Array(data.media_id_string)
      },
        function(err, data, response) {
          if (err){
            console.log('Error!');
            console.log(err);
          }
          else{
            console.log('Posted an image!');
          }
        }
      );
    }
  });
}

setInterval(
  upload_random_image(),
  10000
);
```

Complete error:

```
Opening an image...
Uploading an image...
timers.js:414
    throw new TypeError('"callback" argument must be a function');
    ^

TypeError: "callback" argument must be a function
    at exports.setInterval (timers.js:414:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/imac/test/server.js:72:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:420:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:535:3
```

Comment: You need to fix the two lines that say `if (!err) {` by removing the exclamation marks: `if (err) {` If you do that, the code should work; it did for me. I'm also a bit confused, because the error you mention looks less like an error message and more like a script line that's supposed to throw one; where exactly are you getting this from? The console...?

Comment: I already did that. And still same error. Yep, from the console.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you're getting in your console? The full text?

Comment: @ChrisG yep, give me a sec.

Comment: There is the full txt and my code.

Comment: Open timers.js and look at line 414. In other words, this error has nothing to do with uploading images to twitter.

Comment: `upload_random_image(),` remove the parens and it will work

Comment: GREAT! Thanks Jon!

Comment: @Ghamtre, i posted the answer please check the same.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Background**

`setInterval` [expects a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) as the first parameter.

In your code

```
setInterval(upload_random_image(), 10000);
```

`upload_random_image` is being invoked and return nothing.

**Solution**

Like Karthikeyan mentioned, in order to still invoke upload_random_image, the best thing is to wrap it in a function:

```
setInterval(() => upload_random_image(), 10000)
```

Answer (score 8):

your are declaring the setInterval() incorrect, the correct way is

**setInterval(function(){ upload_random_image() },10000);**

```
var Twit = require('twit')

var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    Twit = require('twit'),
    config = require(path.join(__dirname, 'config.js'));


var T = new Twit(config);

function random_cam(){
  var random_pic = [
    '1.jpg',
    '2.jpg',
    '3.jpg'
  ];
  return random_pic[Math.floor(Math.random() * random_pic.length)];
}


function upload_random_image(){
  console.log('Opening an image...');
  var image_path = path.join(__dirname, '/random_cam/' + random_cam()),
      b64content = fs.readFileSync(image_path, { encoding: 'base64' });

  console.log('Uploading an image...');

  T.post('media/upload', { media_data: b64content }, function (err, data, response) {
    if (err){
      console.log('ERROR');
      console.log(err);
    }
    else{
      console.log('Uploaded an image!');

      T.post('statuses/update', {
        media_ids: new Array(data.media_id_string)
      },
        function(err, data, response) {
          if (err){
            console.log('Error!');
            console.log(err);
          }
          else{
            console.log('Posted an image!');
          }
        }
      );
    }
  });
}

setInterval(function(){
     upload_random_image()
},10000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't wrap your function in another anonymous function per sophia.onion's suggestion. Just remove the brackets so you are passing the function reference and not the executed function.

**Problem**: this executes the function upload_random_image instead of passing it as an argument.

```
setInterval(upload_random_image(), 10000);
```

**Solution**: pass function reference instead of the execution.

```
setInterval(upload_random_image, 10000);
```